# Spark: Like RDD's are Datasets and Dataframes are also immutable?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, rdd, apache-spark-dataset

In Apache Spark, RDD's are immutable.
How about Datasets and Dataframes? Are they mutable or immutable(since the underlying structure still is an RDD)?

Comment: everything is immutable. Every operation returns a new DataFrame/DataSet.

Answer (score 1):

Since Structured APIs like DataFrames/ Datasets are built on top of RDD(Low Level API) which are immutable in nature, Therefore Dataframes/ Datasets are immutable in nature.

RDDs are not just immutable but a deterministic function of their input. It means RDD can be re-created at any time. Everytime a unique identifier is assigned to an RDD.

```
myDF.rdd.id() #Before id

myDF = myDF.withColumn("salary",col("salary")*100)

myDF.rdd.id() #After id
```

Comment: how about the off-heap calculations? Then, I suppose the data structures maintained in off-heap are immutable too.

Answer (score 1):

Dataset belongs to Spark-SQL API,after LogicalPlan and PhysicalPlan,it tran to RDD program. so Dataset is immutable.